# EEA family member with 2 valid residence cards

Tags: eu

I’m a South Africa married to a Norwegian. We lived in the UK for two years where I had a valid UK Residence card (residence card of a family member of a union citizen). We now live in Norway for which I have my Norwegian/EU residence card (residence card family member). Since my UK residence card has not expired, can I use it to travel back to the UK unaccompanied As before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your card is not expired, but it is no longer valid.  From [The Immigration (European Economic Area) Regulations 2016, as amended](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2016/1052), section 18 (Issue of residence card):

> (7) A residence card—
>
> ...
>
> (c) is no longer valid if the holder ceases to have a right to reside under these Regulations;

Therefore, you may not use your UK residence card, and to travel to the UK without your spouse, you must get a visa.